# Can't distinguish between new and edit action in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-admin

I have a product model and which is associated with many product_codes.

I want to hide add product code button from new action and want show that button to edit action. whatever I am configuring its apply for both new and edit action of form.

```
config.model 'Product' do
  edit do

  end
end
```

Comment: In your view you can check `unless @product.new_record?` and only then show the button

Comment: Actually I m using rails admin view. Is their way to generate rails admin views.

Comment: please add the code of what you are doing exactly that applies to both

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can decide to show or mark as read only a field.

```
config.model 'Product' do
  edit do
    field :product_codes do
      read_only do
        product = bindings[:object]  
        product.new_record?
      end

      visible do
        product = bindings[:object]  
        product.new_record?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You decide if you want to hide the field or just make it read only for new product.s